# Write a python Client to pass xs:anyType argument to a webservice method in Java

Tags: java, python, web-services, apache-axis, suds

I have written a small webservice[Axis2/Java] which exposes a method

```
   public String Fill(String cacheName Object... varArgs) {


      return "Sample return "+varArgs[0].toString()+" "+(new Integer(varArgs[1]));

   }
```

My client is a python suds client.

```
import suds;
import suds.client;
url="http://localhost:8989/pakg1/services/JavaCache?wsdl"
client=suds.client.Client(url)
print client.service.Fill("level1,"Immediate",123123);
```

The WSDL shows that the element varArgs as follows.

```
   xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" name="varArgs" nillable="true" type="xs:anyType"
```

However Nothing comes in the Object array at run time. When I try to look at the array in debug mode it show that it is null.

Please advice how do I pass arguments to Fill method so that I can send an array, or a single basic type in varArgs parameter.

Thanks,
Dhawal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is at the axis2 side. The Axis2 is unable to deserialize Object and mistakes it as a DataHandler. I have decided to pass in my Object as OMElement and then deserialize myself.

Have reported the issue with Axis2 also.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried passing your varArgs as a python list?  See if something like this works:

```
client.service.Fill("level1",["Immediate",123123])
```

Comment: To add more info here. The service method Fill receives an Object array of data handlers in varArgs when I do the way you have suggested. Any suggestions??